# How do I implement a generator in a trait in Rust?

Tags: rust

I am trying to implement a generator method in a trait like this:

```
trait TraitWithIterator {
    fn my_iter(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item = u32> + '_ {
        let mut i: u32 = 1;

        ::std::iter::from_fn(move || {
            let res;
            if i <= 10 {
                res = Some(i * i);
                i += 1;
            } else {
                res = None;
            }
            res
        })
    }
}
```

And it gives me the error:

```
error[E0562]: `impl Trait` not allowed outside of function and inherent method return types
```

But everything works fine if I implement the same generator for a structure:

```
struct MyStruct {}

impl MyStruct {
    fn my_iter(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item = u32> + '_ {
        let mut i: u32 = 1;

        ::std::iter::from_fn(move || {
            let res;
            if i <= 10 {
                res = Some(i * i);
                i += 1;
            } else {
                res = None;
            }
            res
        })
    }
}
```

How do I implement the generator for the trait `TraitWithIterator` correctly?

Comment: AFAIK you cannot have `impl Trait` in a trait definition. You can see where it is allowed here: https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2018/trait-system/impl-trait-for-returning-complex-types-with-ease.html

Comment: @IbraheemAhmed Nope. It does not explain how to implement a generator there.

Comment: @Shepmaster's answer applies here. Return a `Box<dyn Iterator>`: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2226eaff641040f2e73859e4d6750d36

Comment: @IbraheemAhmed I see. Thank you, it helped.